# Insert one line into all executable shell scripts in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have three directories:

1. `unix` which contains some .sh files and some non executable files
2. `unix2` (subdirectory of `unix`) which contains some other .sh files and some non executable files
3. `unix3` (subdirectory of `unix2`) which contains some other .sh files and some non executable files

What I want to do is to run through all executable files of all directories
and then insert an echo command in the second line of each file.
Notice that I want to write this in a bash script and run it in Desktop at Unix environment.

Im working on ubuntu,
I have tried to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f - name '*.sh' | sed -i 's/oldcommand/newcommand/' *.sh
```

But it will only work in .sh files that are located in Desktop.
Any help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What is giving you problems?  Which tools are available for you to use? Are there any other subdirectories under `unix` that must not be processed?  Is it sufficient to go by file permissions to determine which files are executable?  Are there any executable binary files, or executable Perl scripts to worry about?

Comment: no there are no other subdirectories  or executable perl scripts to worry about

Comment: Try `find . -type f - name '*.sh' -exec sed -i 's/oldcommand/newcommand/' {} \;`

Comment: Although it seems as though your sed should be inserting a line rather than doing a simple replacement.

Comment: `find unix -type f -name '*.sh' -exec sed -i '1a echo "Hello World"' {} +` limits the changes to shell files in the `unix` subdirectory and its sub-directories, and uses GNU `sed` notation to add a line that says `echo "Hello World"` as the second line in the file.

Comment: erro: missing argument to -exec

Comment: Jonathan Leffler thank you so much,this totally worked!